# How to evaluate an Eff monad in psci?

Tags: purescript

I'm learning Purescript using the [purescript-node-http](https://github.com/purescript-node/purescript-node-http) library. If I have a value whose type is the following:

```
> :t f
forall t3.
  Eff
    ( http :: HTTP
    , console :: CONSOLE
    | t3
    )
    Request
```

How would I be able to evaluate this in psci and assign the `Request` return value to a variable?

Comment: `let` and `unsafePerformEff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind the result to a variable right now. That feature might be supported in a later version. Note that you *can* evaluate the result and print it out.

If you use the browser as your evaluation environment (with `--port`) then one option is to store the result in a `Ref` and use the `Ref` later to retrieve the value.

The problem with the Node backend is that there is no persistent state, so that approach would not be possible at all with the Node backend.